# How to add a Controls.Grid in a Canvas

Tags: c#, canvas

I would like add a Grid in a Canvas and put inside a Rectangle.

Here my code

```
        Grid gridForModules = new Grid();       
        Canvas.SetLeft(gridForModules, 600);
        Canvas.SetTop(gridForModules, 80);
        AddRowsOfGrid(gridForModules, 5);
        AddColumnsOfGrid(gridForModules, 8);
        gridForModules.ShowGridLines = true;
        m_grid.RegisterName("ModulesGRID", gridForModules);
        m_canvas.Children.Add(gridForModules);


        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        Grid.SetColumn(rect, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(rect, 2);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(rect, 2);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(rect, 2);
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Coral);
        rect.Name = "ModuloEsempio";
        gridForModules.Children.Add(rect);
        m_grid.RegisterName(rect.Name, rect);
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as expected when you use your code?

Comment: I don't see the lines of the grid and I don't see the rectangle.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in my tests. Have you set the `Height` of your RowDefinitions in `AddRowsOfGrid` and the `Width` of your ColumnDefinitions in `AddColumnsOfGrid`? If yes, can you post the code of that methods? (Remember that your Grid is a bit far on the right due to a `SetLeft` of `600`.)

Comment: private void AddColumnsOfGrid(Grid grid, int numberOfColumns)
        {  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
            {  ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
                col.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);  }  }
        private void AddRowsOfGrid(Grid grid, int numberOfRows)
        {  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; ++i){RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                row.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row); }}

Comment: sorry for the post unreadable, but I tried to put it in the first post, but told me that there was too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify that the columns/rows of the Grid should be equally wide/high by setting `new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star)` on both. So if you have 5 rows then the height of each row should be the height of the Grid divided by 5.

The problem in your code is that the Grid doesn't have a height or width because the Canvas is just a drawing board that doesn't size its contents.

To solve your problem you either have to set the size on the Grid using

```
gridForModules.Width = 300;
gridForModules.Height = 200;
```

or you have to set it in the Column/RowDefinitions

```
col.Width = new GridLength(30);
row.Height = new GridLength(30);
```

After that you should see your Grid and your Rectangle (if you look a bit far to the right).